# Failure to restore from S3 backup using Datastax Opscenter

Tags: backup, datastax, restore, opscenter

I have an existing Cassandra DSE cluster managed by Opscenter with a backup schedule of all keyspaces to a S3 bucket. I spinned up a fresh cluster (with a separate instance of Opscenter) to attempt a full restore of the backup and I'm facing several issues;

Firstly, it's impossible to trigger a restore from the opscenter UI, after selecting "restore from a different location", entering the location, selecting all keyspaces and confirming the restore operation, after some time I'm getting a dialog with what I assume is a JS error: `cannot read property "message" of undefined`. Looking at the request on the network tab, I see the following nginx response:

```html
<html><head>
<meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html;charset=utf-8">
<title>502 Server Error</title>
</head>
<body text=#000000 bgcolor=#ffffff>
<h1>Error: Server Error</h1>
<h2>The server encountered a temporary error and could not complete your request.<p>Please try again in 30 seconds.</h2>
<h2></h2>
</body></html>
```

I looked carefully at the Opscenter documentation and couldn't find any timeout configuration that might correlate to this. As a plan B I attempted to trigger the restore operation from the command line (basically copying the request as curl and running it on the opscenter node), here I faced different issues. The first attempts failed after some time with errors similar to:

`{"message": "Failure applying schema change <REDACTED_CREATE_TABLE_QUERY>, failed to completed because: com.datastax.driver.core.exceptions.InvalidQueryException: Unknown type <REDACTED_KEYSPACE>.<REDACTED_TABLE>. ", "type": "AlterSchemaFailed"}`

I find this very curious, because again, this is a fresh cluster with no data whatsoever. To solve this I had to `cqlsh` into the cluster and manually create the keyspaces and tables it was complaining about (this happened 3 times).

After that I got a different error which required me to add `"force_schema": true` to the request. After doing that, I finally managed to get a normal response and I could see the restore process running on the UI. The restore itself failed after some time with different errors, such as:

`Failed query to http://10.32.4.6:61621/v1/ops/restore/<BACKUP_NAME>/<KEYSPACE_NAME>?req-id=6925a343-9900-4765-b239-128175f4dd6d&parent_req=5fab0458-b377-4107-b899-b35a18762379 : org.httpkit.ProtocolException: No status`

Comment: Which version of opscenter are you using? Can you tell me more about your browser and its version as well? Let's focus on getting your UI issue sorted out first, as it'll make your life a bit easier in the end. Restore via the API can be tricky as there can be schema conflicts, so it's important to read over the API docs first https://docs.datastax.com/en/opscenter/6.1/api/docs/backups.html#method-restore-backup.

Comment: @tom.alexander I figured out that the nginx error page was coming from kubernetes, since the backend timeout was set to 30 seconds. The other issues have been resolved after tweaking the HEAP for all components. The only issue I have now is that the restore fails for a missing column that was dropped in the past. The keyspace description holds no information about it, yet the restore process fails because of it. When exploring further I found an entry for it under `system_schema.dropped_columns`. This can be fixed by creating the column and then dropping it on the destination cluster.